# how can I use loop increment inside javascript ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

I'm little stuck here, can anybody help?

I have a list of items and for each item I need to call ajax. After returning data I will process them, but with context of particular item. Please look in source code below. My problem is, that i always get i=5 for all my items. Any suggestions?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $.ajax(myAjaxUrl)
        .done(function(myAjaxResponse) {
            doSomething(myAjaxResponse, i);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("ajax response fail");
            doSomething("", i);
        });
}

function doSomething(text, i) {
    console.log(text + " " + i);
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: You will have to implement a lock of some sort. [SO: jQuery Ajax SyncLock](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2151648/1762224)

Comment: Better dupe is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Use `$.each(new Array(5), function(i) { /* your body */ })` instead of `for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { /* your body */ }`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26414099/947687